# ScrollView overlaps ActionBar, prevents buttons selected

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

When I change the layout of a fragment within an activity, the menu options in the action bar seem to stop working.  The buttons (Search icon and NavDrawer icon) become unresponsive.

This is the layout file of the fragment with the working menu options:
**activity_login.xml (working)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Login."
            android:id="@+id/login_title_text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAlt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <!-- E-mail section -->
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="E-mail address"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/login_emailField"
            android:layout_above="@+id/login_passwordField" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/register_email_icon"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/login_emailField"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


        <!-- Password section -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/register_password_icon"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/login_passwordField"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:id="@+id/login_passwordField"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/login_login_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_passwordField"
            android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#E91E63"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/material_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="13dp"
                android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="Login" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Forgotten your username or password?"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_login_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/login_footer_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Tap here"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_footer_text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/loginForgottenTapText"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the layout file that seems to break the buttons:
**activity_login.xml (non-working)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Login."
            android:id="@+id/login_title_text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAlt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <!-- E-mail section -->
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="E-mail address"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/login_emailField"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_title_text" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/register_email_icon"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/login_emailField"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


        <!-- Password section -->

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_emailField"
            android:id="@+id/login_passwordField"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/register_password_icon"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/login_passwordField"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/login_login_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_passwordField"
            android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#E91E63"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/material_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="13dp"
                android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="Login" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Forgotten your username or password?"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_login_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/login_footer_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Tap here"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_footer_text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/loginForgottenTapText"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, LoginFragment.OnLoginCallback {

    MenuItem register;
    MenuItem login;
    MenuItem logout;
    MenuItem completeListing;
    MenuItem expiredListing;
    MenuItem activeListing;

    NavigationView navigationView;
    UserCredentialHandler userStatus;

    protected static final String KEY_USER_STATUS = "USER_STATUS";
    protected static final String USER_PREFS = "userNamePrefs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        userStatus = new UserCredentialHandler();

        final HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateListingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        getMenuItems(navigationView);

        if(userStatus.checkIfUserIsLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
            userStatus.setNavHeaderOnLogin(getApplicationContext(), navigationView);
            updateNavDrawer("login", register, login, logout, expiredListing, completeListing, activeListing);
        } else {
            userStatus.setNavHeaderOnLogout(navigationView);
            updateNavDrawer("logout", register, login, logout, expiredListing, completeListing, activeListing);
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,homeFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        userStatus.setNavHeaderOnLogin(getApplicationContext(), navigationView);

        updateNavDrawer("login",register,login,logout, expiredListing, completeListing, activeListing);

        register.setVisible(false);
        login.setVisible(false);
        logout.setVisible(true);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,homeFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.search_mag_icon){
            SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_container, searchFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_register) {
            final RegisterFragment registerFragment = new RegisterFragment();

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_container, registerFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
            final LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_container, loginFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

        } else if(id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            userStatus.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
            userStatus.setNavHeaderOnLogout(navigationView);
            updateNavDrawer("logout",register,login,logout, expiredListing, completeListing, activeListing);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_listings) {
            // navigate to my listings
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_how) {
            // navigate to how it works page
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
            // navigate to help page
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact_us) {
            // navigate to contact page,
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void updateNavDrawer(String action, MenuItem register, MenuItem login, MenuItem logout, MenuItem expiredListing, MenuItem completeListing, MenuItem activeListing){
        if(action=="login"){
            register.setVisible(false);
            login.setVisible(false);
            logout.setVisible(true);
            completeListing.setVisible(true);
            activeListing.setVisible(true);
            expiredListing.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            register.setVisible(true);
            login.setVisible(true);
            logout.setVisible(false);
            completeListing.setVisible(false);
            activeListing.setVisible(false);
            expiredListing.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    private void getMenuItems(NavigationView nv){
        register = nv.getMenu().getItem(0);
        login = nv.getMenu().getItem(1);
        logout = nv.getMenu().getItem(2);
        activeListing = nv.getMenu().getItem(3);
        completeListing = nv.getMenu().getItem(4);
        expiredListing = nv.getMenu().getItem(5);
    }

}
```

I cannot seem to workout why changing the layout is breaking the ActionBar menu options, any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
Changing the `<ScrollView>` element to `<LinearLayout>` seems to solve it but I need a ScrollView.  The ScrollView seems to overlap the ActionBar and is on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting android:layout_height on the ScrollView to "match_parent" instead of "wrap_content"